# Time-dependent mesh deformation

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh

I want to display the result of a deformation with a mesh, but I solved the deformation with a time dependency. So I have two functions: `uxsol[t,x,y]` and `uysol[t,x,y]`

I tried to fix t to get the mesh:

```
uxsolmesh[x_, y_] = uxsol[1, x, y];    //t=1 here
uysolmesh[x_, y_] = uysol[1, x, y];    //t=1 here
```

but when I attempt to display the mesh with

```
mesh = uxsolmesh["ElementMesh"];
```

> ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {uxsolmesh, uysolmesh}]["Wireframe"]

nothing appears. Does someone knows how I can solve this?

For more informations, here the code :

```
eq1 = (Y/(2*(1 + nu)*(1 - 2*nu)))*(D[D[ux[t, x, y], x], x] + 
  D[D[uy[t, x, y], x], y]) + (Y/(1 + nu))*(D[D[t, ux[x, y], x], 
   x] + D[D[t, ux[x, y], y], y]) - ro*D[D[ux[t, x, y], t], t];   

eq2 = (Y/(2*(1 + nu)*(1 - 2*nu)))*(D[D[ux[t, x, y], y], x] + 
      D[D[uy[t, x, y], y], y]) + (Y/(1 + nu))*(D[D[uy[t, x, y], x], 
       x] + D[D[uy[t, x, y], y], y]) - ro*g - 
   ro*D[D[uy[t, x, y], t], t];

{uxsol, uysol} = NDSolveValue[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0,
    DirichletCondition[{ux[t, x, y] == 0, uy[t, x, y] == 0}, x == 0],
    DirichletCondition[{ux[t, x, y] == 0, uy[t, x, y] == 0}, t == 0]
    }, {ux, uy}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 100}];

uxsolmesh[x_, y_] = uxsol[1, x, y]; 
uysolmesh[x_, y_] = uysol[1, x, y];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]    
mesh = uxsolmesh["ElementMesh"];
ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {uxsolmesh, uysolmesh}]["Wireframe"]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please add working code to make reproduction of your problem possible. Otherwise answering will be difficult.

Comment: The output `ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {uxsolmesh, uysolmesh}]` shows that `mesh` is undefined.  (I think.)

Comment: It probably should be `mesh = uxsol["ElementMesh"]`, but it's hard to check since `eq1` and `eq2` were left out.  Could you include them?

Comment: (1) Is `ux` to be a function of `t,x,y` or just `x,y`?  (2) Please remember to format your code.  The `{}` button above the edit window will indent a code block four spaces if it is selected.  Thanks.

Comment: You might need to load a specific package first (``<< NDSolve`FEM` ``).

Comment: ux and uy are fonctions of {t,x,y}

Comment: In `eq1` and `eq2`, `ux` and `uy` are functions of `x,y` only.  (Don't you get an error message when you execute the code you posted?)

Comment: indeed i paste the wrong part of the code, i corrected this, and ux and uy are function of t,x,y

Comment: I get the error when running the code: `NDSolveValue::femcnsd : The PDE coefficient g ro does not evaluate to numeric scalar`

Answer (score 3):

First, let's assign some numbers to the unspecified parameters and shorten the `t` interval of integration to something more reasonable for a minimal working example.

```
g = ro = nu = Y = 1;

{uxsol, uysol} = NDSolveValue[{
    eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[{ux[t, x, y] == 0, uy[t, x, y] == 0}, x == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[{ux[t, x, y] == 0, uy[t, x, y] == 0}, t == 0]},
   {ux, uy}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

We can see that one problem in achieving the OP's desired result is that the element mesh is a 3D hexahedral mesh, not a 2D mesh.

```
emesh = uxsol["ElementMesh"];
emesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So we need to slice it (or project it onto 2D -- I'm not sure of the best term).  I don't know of a built-in way to do this, but it's a fairly straightforward matter, if you've read the Element Mesh documentation and especially [`QuadElement`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/QuadElement.html).

We can find the vertices and quadratic nodes of the slice of the mesh given by `t == 0.`  (The coordinates are laid out so that the quadratic nodes of the entire mesh follow the vertices of the mesh.)

```
{cpos, qcpos} = With[{c = emesh["Coordinates"]},
  With[{pos = Flatten@ Position[c, {0., _, _}]},
   Span @@@ Partition[
     Extract[pos, 
      Join[
       {{1}}, 
       Join[#, # + 1] &@ SparseArray[Differences@pos - 1]["NonzeroPositions"],
       {{-1}}]
      ], 2]
   ]]

(*  {1 ;; 168, 9241 ;; 9542}  *)
```

Next, we need to construct the incidents for each element; they also follow a regular pattern, which can be seen in the `Table` commands.  They can be plugged into `ToElementMesh`.

```
With[{c = emesh["Coordinates"][[cpos, 2 ;; 3]],
  qc = emesh["Coordinates"][[qcpos, 2 ;; 3]]},
 With[{ht = Count[c, {c[[1, 1]], _}]},
  With[{i = Flatten[Table[{ht (x - 1) + y, ht (x - 1) + y + ht, 
        ht (x - 1) + y + ht + 1, ht (x - 1) + y + 1},
       {x, Length@c/ht - 1}, {y, ht - 1}], 1],
    qi = Length@c +
     Flatten[Table[{(2 ht - 1) (x - 1) + y + ht - 1, (2 ht - 1) x + y,
         (2 ht - 1) (x - 1) + y + ht, (2 ht - 1) (x - 1) + y},
       {x, Length@qc/(2 ht - 1)}, {y, ht - 1}], 1]},
   tmesh = ToElementMesh[
     "Coordinates" -> Join[c, qc],
     "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[MapThread[Join, {i, qi}]]}
     ];
   tmesh["Wireframe"]
   ]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The element mesh deformation is also straightforward, except that the magnitude of the deformation in places causes some mesh elements to intersect themselves and other elements.  To avoid this, scale down the deformation.

```
(* scale effect by 1/400 *)
xfn = Function[{x, y}, uxsol[1, x, y]/400]; 
yfn = Function[{x, y}, uysol[1, x, y]/400];

Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
xifn = ElementMeshInterpolation[{tmesh}, xfn @@@ tmesh["Coordinates"]];
yifn = ElementMeshInterpolation[{tmesh}, yfn @@@ tmesh["Coordinates"]];
dmesh = ElementMeshDeformation[tmesh, {xifn, yifn}];
dmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can even color the mesh by the magnitude of the deformation.

```
deform = Norm /@ (dmesh["Coordinates"] - tmesh["Coordinates"]);
Legended[Show[
  Graphics@ElementMeshToGraphicsComplex[dmesh, All, 
    VertexColors -> ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[deform]], 
  dmesh["Wireframe"]], 
 Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow", Through[{Min, Max}[deform]]}, 
   LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Since your code isn't working it is hard to deduce what is the problem. However to deform a mesh it is a quite simple task not using `ElementMeshDeformation[]`. You can change the coordinates of the mesh, but leave the mesh elements unchanged. Then feed those arguments into `ToElementMesh[]` function.

Here the original mesh of a disk is created, and then coordinates of the mesh points are randomly updated.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Circle[]];
c = mesh["Coordinates"];
el = mesh["MeshElements"];
cn = c + RandomReal[{-0.05, 0.05 + 0 t}, {Length[c], 2}];
newMesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> cn, "MeshElements" -> el];
newMesh["Wireframe"]
```

The code using Manipulate:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh = ToElementMesh[Circle[]];

Manipulate[
 If[t == 0, cn = c; 
  , cn = c + RandomReal[{-0.05 , 0.05 + 0 t}, {Length[c], 2}]];
 changedMesh = 
  Quiet@ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> cn, "MeshElements" -> el];
 changedMesh["Wireframe"]
 , {t, 0, 1, .1}, 
 Initialization :> {c = mesh["Coordinates"], 
   el = mesh["MeshElements"]}]
```

The result is:

[image]